# Importing csv data to SQL using PowerShell

Tags: sql, powershell

Hi Glorius People of the Interwebz!

I come to you with a humble question (please go easy on me, I am fairly OK in PowerShell, but my SQL skills are minimal... :( )

So I have been tasked with to write a powershell script to import data (from a number of csv files to a database) and I made a good progress, based on [this](https://virtuallysober.com/2018/06/06/importing-csv-files-into-a-microsoft-sql-db-using-powershell/) (I heavily modified my version). All works dashingly, except one part: when I try to insert the values (I created a sort of "mapping file" to map the csv headers to the data), I can't seem to use the created string in the values part. So here is what I have:

[This is my current code for powershell](https://code.prkr.li/arU1C9Ih1n) (ignore the comments)

[This is a sample data csv](https://code.prkr.li/8U5aAqlvNl)

[This is my mapping file](https://code.prkr.li/qDashQz1Pd)

What I would want, is to replace the

```
 VALUES(
            '$($CSVLine.Invoice_Status_Text)',  
            '$($CSVLine.Invoice_Status)', 
            '$($CSVLine.Dispute_Required_Text)',
            '$($CSVLine.Dispute_Required)', 
            '$($CSVLine.Dispute_Resolved_Text)',
            '$($CSVLine.Dispute_Resolved)',
            '$($CSVLine.Sub_Account_Number)',
            '$($CSVLine.QTY)',
            '$($CSVLine.Date_of_Service)',
            '$($CSVLine.Service)',
            '$($CSVLine.Amount_of_Service)',
            '$($CSVLine.Total)',
            '$($CSVLine.Location)',
            '$($CSVLine.Dispute_Reason_Text)',
            '$($CSVLine.Dispute_Reason)',

            '$($CSVLine.Numeric_counter)'
            );"
```

[Part, for example with a string generated this way:](https://code.prkr.li/Nmg0x0PmdS)

But when I replace the long - and honestly, boring to type - values with the $valueString, I get this type of error:

```
Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing '$($'.
```

Not sure, if it matters, but my PS is 7.1

Any good people who can give a good suggestion on how to build the values from my text file...?

Ta,
F.

Comment: Try with double-quotes (`"`) instead of single-quotes (`'`). Single quotyes take whatever is in between literally, while double quotes interpolate the variables. so in your function do `$valuesString = foreach ($string in $headers) { '"{0}"' -f ($placeholder -replace '__replaceme__' , $string) }`

Comment: Not sure if I get it right, but I changed the code for this:

 $headers = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\SQL\ImportingCSVsIntoSQLv1\config\headers.txt'
 $headersString = $headers -join ', '

 $placeholder = '$($CSVLine.__replaceme__)'
 $valuesString = @()
 foreach ($string in $headers){
    $value = '"{0}"' -f ($placeholder -replace '__replaceme__' , $string)
    
    $valuesString += $value
 }
 
 $valuesString = $valuesString -join ',
 '
This results in :

"$($CSVLine.Numeric_counter)",
 "$($CSVLine.Invoice_Status_Text)"
....

But still I get the error... :(

Comment: When you say SQL, are you referring to SQL Server?  Some DBMS products come with a utility that can read csv files into a table.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, wrapping variables inside single-quotes takes the variable as written literally, so you do not get the value contained (`7957`), but a string like `$($CSVLine.Numeric_counter)` instead.

I don't do SQL a lot, but I think I would change the part where you construct the values to insert like this:

```
# demo, read the csv file in your example
$csv = Import-Csv D:\Test\test.csv -Delimiter ';'

# demo, these are the headers (or better yet, the Property Names to use from the objects in the CSV) as ARRAY  
# (you use `$headers = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Temp\SQL\ImportingCSVsIntoSQLv1\config\headers.txt'`)
$headers = 'Invoice_Status_Text','Invoice_Status','Dispute_Required_Text','Dispute_Required',
           'Dispute_Resolved_Text','Dispute_Resolved','Sub_Account_Number','QTY','Date_of_Service',
           'Service','Amount_of_Service','Total','Location','Dispute_Reason_Text','Dispute_Reason','Numeric_counter'

# capture formatted blocks of values for each row in the CSV
$AllValueStrings = $csv | ForEach-Object {
    # get a list of values using propertynames you have in the $headers
    $values = foreach ($propertyName in $headers) {
        $value = $_.$propertyName
        # output the VALUE to be captured in $values
        # for SQL, single-quote the string type values. Numeric values without quotes
        if ($value -match '^[\d\.]+$') { $value }
        else { "'{0}'" -f $value }
    }
    # output the values for this row in the CSV
    $values -join ",`r`n"
}

# $AllValueStrings will now have as many formatted values to use 
# in the SQL as there are records (rows) in the csv
$AllValueStrings
```

Using your examples, $AllValueStrings would yield

```
'Ready To Pay',
1,
'No',
2,
'',
'',
'',
'',
'',
'',
'',
'',
'',
'',
'',
7957
```

Comment: Thanks. This almost gets me where I want, but I would need to use instead the value of one csv, the values of many. my $CSVImport = @() is actually gets created like this:
$dataFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $dataFolder *.csv
    foreach ($d in $dataFiles) {
$CSVImport += Import-Csv $($d.FullName) -Delimiter ';'
}

When I replace the $csv in your code with $csvImport, it appears to not importing anything :(

I will try to work out how to fix it, I am sure I will be able to eventually!

Comment: @krapulax Try importing like this: `$CSVImport = Import-Csv -Path (Get-ChildItem -Path $dataFolder -Filter '*.csv' -File).FullName -Delimiter ';'`

Comment: Thanks mate. That does not changed my outcome so far.
Will give it some more attempt later, and will try to work out what I am missing.
Here is my full code
https://github.com/fabricesemti80/ImportingCSVsIntoSQLv1